# Facebook Android SDK - Show news feed API version 2.5

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make my android app to show the news feed of a profile after the login. I already have access to the access token and profile id through the Facebook Login. My app uses api version 2.5 and the facebook documentation states that the extended permission "read_stream" , used for home permission, is no longer accessible(deprecated for versions 2.3 and higher). How can i access the read stream for this version? Is it possible to change my app's api version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user_posts` permission is the replacement for `read_stream`, there is no way to get the whole stream anymore - only posts of the user and posts of his friends made on the wall of the authorized user. It´s in the changelog too.